# How to add title in export chart in highchart?

Tags: svg, highcharts

I am exporting the six chart side by side.I am able to export multiple chart but not able to add Title on top of chart. I have tried but the title is overlapped with chart title.

> `My Implemented code:`[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameekmishra/tgkt9ntb/11/)

[image]

please suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: You can change your getSVG method in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/tgkt9ntb/12/

Comment: Thanks,It's working.